# Drag and drop HTML5 and browser cache

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to html5 and I gone through some tutorial about HTML5.Now I want to do something in html5. Please suggest me

I have 3 canvas

canvas1 having collection of button. assume with name of A,B,C,1,2,3

I want to drag these buttons to canvas2 and canvas3

canvas2 should only accept character type of buttons(A,B,C)
canvas3 should only accept numeric type of buttons(1,2,3)

Once I refresh the page all buttons are stored in browser cache

using HTML5 and javascript

Comment: You can't have a collection of buttons on a `canvas`, only a collection of pixels.  It's not clear what you're trying to do here, what have you attempted so far?  Please add any code you have to the question.

Comment: @robertc:-ok..Inside the pixel we have a text like A,B,1,2..etc. I need to drag letter pixels to one canvas and number pixels to another canvas.. got it

Comment: You still just have pixels, once you've drawn the text it no longer exists as an independent object that you can manipulate.  You don't have 'letters', you just have pixels.